# How to force EditText to start text with capital letter?

Tags: android

I have an `EditText` and I need the text in it (when user types in) to be started with capital letter.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Be careful if you add both `android:capitalize="sentences"` and `android:inputType="text"`, as the latter seems to have priority over the first and the input will not be capitalized.

There's a specific `inputType` for automatically capitalizing the first letter:

`android:inputType="textCapSentences"`

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType

Comment: Nice tip!  I had both and it worked as expected on a Nexus One and a Galaxy Nexus.  But on an HTC Sense device, the words were not capitalized. android:inputType was the trick.

Comment: Word of warning: since in my case the field was going to be a person's name, I set android:inputType="textPersonName". This did not work as expected: I had to use android:inputType="textCapWords" to get each word of the name to capitalize.

Comment: android:capitalize="sentences"  should not use this tag bcuz it is deprecated

Comment: What if android:inputType="textMultiLine"?

Comment: Then use `android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"`

Comment: Its not working with google material **om.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText**

Answer (score 24):

The options for **android:capitalize** are

```
android:inputType="none", which won't automatically capitalize anything.

android:inputType="sentences", Which will capitalize the first word of each sentence.

android:inputType="words", Which Will Capitalize The First Letter Of Every Word.

android:inputType="characters", WHICH WILL CAPITALIZE EVERY CHARACTER.
```

Apparently it has been changed to `inputType` instead of `capitalize`

Comment: This method is deprecated.

Comment: @h8pathak inputType should be used in favor of this method.

Comment: you can use 
            android:inputType="textCapWords"

Comment: @SadiqueKhan would you mind adding to the answer with an edit? I answered this 10 years ago. I would hope that the syntax has changed a bit.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 18):

Use

```
android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"
```

as using only `"textPersonName"` is not enough so name's first letters would be capitalized.

Similarly with postal addresses:

```
android:inputType="textPostalAddress|textCapSentences"
```

Comment: Doesn't work good with names like "da Silva" or "von Anhalt".

Answer (score 8):

Try this way,

```
testEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS);
```

or `android:inputType="textCapSentences"` will only work If your device keyboard *Auto Capitalize* Setting enabled.

Comment: accepted answer is great but I was looking for coding answer, this works. tx

Answer (score 8):

Add this in your `XML`

```
 android:inputType="textCapWords"
```

`android:inputType="textCapSentences"` will work for sentences. However, I needed to capitalize every word in a full name field.

Answer (score 3):

In the layout xml, add `android:inputType=textCapSentences`

Answer (score 3):

You used the word "Enforce". So try this. Just pass your edittext as argument.

```
public static void setCapitalizeTextWatcher(final EditText editText) {
    final TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        int mStart = 0;

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            mStart = start + count;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
             String input = s.toString();
            String capitalizedText;
            if (input.length() < 1)
                capitalizedText = input;
            else
                capitalizedText = input.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + input.substring(1);
            if (!capitalizedText.equals(editText.getText().toString())) {
                editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        editText.setSelection(mStart);
                        editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                    }
                });
                editText.setText(capitalizedText);
            }
        }
    };

    editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the layout xml, add [`android:capitalize="sentences"`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3acapitalize)

Answer (score 2):

In case of password which starts from upper case it will be:

`android:inputType="textPassword|textCapSentences"`

Answer (score 2):

in case you ran into the annoying case of setting android:inputType=textCapSentences then ending up with one-liner EditText, here's the solution:

```
    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
```

Answer (score 1):

Paste this in your edittext (xml):

```
  android:capitalize="sentences"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
edittext.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.AllCaps()});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Adding input type in edit text as textCapSentences which will make first letter of the sentence capital

```
        <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        android:hint="Name"/>
```