# How to first letter capital in android , How to capitalise first letter in android?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, capitalization, letter

I want forcefully add first letter capital in `EditText`. So i can search about i get lots of solution but i *Notice that user can **shift** and **enter** lower characters.*

I tried below code :

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences|textCapWords"
```

Also I tried pragmatically :

```
EditText editor = new EditText(this); 
editor.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
```

Any other solution. If user **shift** and **enter** lower characters it's automatically converted in to Upper characters.

Comment: what about doing that programmatically...???

Comment: It's work but when user can **shift** and **enter** lower character then it take lower so i want to forcefully convert into uppercase. @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ

Comment: You want every word's first letter as capital?? OR just first letter of each sentence??

Comment: First letter of each sentence @NaitikSoni

Comment: You can try `OnFocusChangeListener` on edittext, and than alter your text.

Comment: `OnFocusChangeListener` how to i manage using this can you please explain more. @NaitikSoni

Comment: Sorry for late reply...Is your EditText multiline? or single line?

Comment: Single line.. @NaitikSoni

Answer (score 1):

Try `InputFilter` here is working snipped. modify code acording your need.

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextId);

editText..setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter }); 

InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() { 
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) { 
    for (int i = start;i < end;i++) { 
        if (!Character.isLetter(source.charAt(0))) { 
            return ""; 
        } 
    } 
    return null; 
} 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simple solution** - Cannot restrict user to type first character capital so

When the user is done writing get the string value from `edittext` then change the first letter to capital and use that string.

ie
On `Button click` or so get the `string` value from `edittext`

```
String content = edtEditText.getText().toString();
content.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello Guys Below code is worked for me.

```
val toUpperCaseFilter =
        InputFilter { source, start, end, dest, dstart, dend ->
            val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
            for (i in start until end) {
                var character = source[i]
                if(i==0 || source[i-1].equals(' ',true)) {
                    character = Character.toUpperCase(character!!) // THIS IS UPPER CASING
                }
                stringBuilder.append(character)
            }
            stringBuilder.toString()
        }

    binding.edtUsername.setFilters(arrayOf(toUpperCaseFilter))
```

This will work in every device and every keyboard.

Comment: This is the correct approach, but I found some issues though...When u are trying to write an email, all letters after the @ will be caps, which is not what we want...Use this kotlin code inside the for instead: var character = source[i]
                if (source.length == 1 && dest.isEmpty()) {
                    character = Character.toUpperCase(character)
                }
                stringBuilder.append(character)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set `android:capitalize="sentences"` in your XML file, No need to set other "textCapWords" in `android:inputType`, as the latter seems to have priority over the first and the input will not be capitalized.

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386291/how-to-force-edittext-to-start-text-with-capital-letter

Comment: Please you check @DeadlyChambers answer comment in your given link. This method is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Try a text watcher like following

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

    et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

           if(count ==1){
              Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0));
           }
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    });
```

Comment: In if condition it's give me a error like : `Cannot resolve method 'toUpperCase(java.lang.CharSequence)'`

Comment: Try `Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0));`

Comment: Yes you are right , I missed that . I am editing my answer @NaitikSoni

Comment: This is not working when i shift and enter lower character. @MithunSarkerShuvro

Comment: This won't work because u are not assigning the upper case change to anything...if u try to assign it to your edittext inside the listener, u'll create an infinite loop...this is not a correct answer...look at Mayuresh Deshmukh's answer below...that's the correct approach...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:inputType="textCapWords"` to capitalize every word and `android:inputType="textCapSentences"` for capitalising every sentence